# MvvmCross + android launch app bisbehaving

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am being facing an strange issue on my xamarin.android + mvvmcross app.

The strange thing is while we install the app manually using signed apk and immediately click on open button to launch the app then it does not work properly but when we click on the done button and launch the app from the app icon then it work as required to be...

I am not sure what might be causing this problem to occur.

Note: we are using MVVMCROSS for data binding and navigation.

please help me out to resolve this problem and also let me know if any more information required.

Thanks
Aaman

Comment: I haven't seen that issue before. Have you tried a simple app to see if you can reproduce it? Try one without MvvmCross and one with. It could just be your project. Also, I replaced the default DebugTrace class to write to the Android log. This way I can open the log viewer and see what MvvmCross is doing.

Comment: It really sounds like you have some values that you set after the app ran the first time? When you start the app the second time its apparently depending on those values, but unable to read them. I would write to logcat and check what is going on.

Comment: we are not doing such stuff on app run first time...I am not sure whether this is happening because of mvvmcross viewmodel lifecycle issue...but in order to fix this issue we have simply navigating to initial view by client code not from the mvvmcross navigation and also set the intent flags as cleartop,cleartask,newtask.....
Note:- Not pointing this might be the mvvmcross issue